# Monotouch.Dialog: how to preselect an element from a RadioGroup?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have an element in my Monotouch.Dialog Controller that discloses a list of possible selections (RadioGroup with many RadioElements).
If one of the elements is picked, I pop one controller of my stack and the element that showed the subitems now shows the selected item’s value.

However, if the dialog gets initialized I want to set the element's current value.
I tried setting the section's "Selected" property but that does not seem to do the trick.

I noticed that the RadioGroup constructor has an index that allows selecting but how can I change the selection *afterwards*?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly but it seems that MT.D samples (on github) has a few uses that are identical to this ? If not then maybe some code will help us (or at least me ;-) understand your issue. https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample

Comment: Not really. See demoElementApi.cs. It has some RadioGroups but the preselected item is always constant. Some RadioGroup constructors are initialized with index 0 others with 2, preselecting the corresponding item. What I want: my radio groups and options are already there. I don't know which one is selected when they get constructed. I want to select one of the possible elements later. Clearer now? Let's say the selection of one radio group is supposed to change if the user toggles a Boolean element for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found it. Well hidden in the RootElement. The property is "`RadioSelected`".

Comment: Any chance of posting a code snippet to see how you've done this?  i'm looking in to the same issue.

Comment: var `radioRoot = new RootElement ("Some Radio Root", new RadioGroup (0));`- then add some `RadioElements` - then preselect 2nd radio element: `radioRoot.RadioSelected = 2;`